# Golang json.Unmarshal invalid character '\n' in string literal

Tags: json, go

Golang json.Unmarshal throws error for newline character. [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/pod2w6_UhOz)

How to unmarshal data if string contains newline?

Comment: Newline is a control character it must be escaped.

Comment: A literal newline is illegal in a JSON string. The JSON is syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply escaping the newline character should do the trick:

```
var val []byte = []byte(`"{\"channel\":\"buupr\\niya\",\"name\":\"john\", \"msg\":\"doe\"}"`)
```

The output for the above:

```
{"channel":"buupr\niya","name":"john", "msg":"doe"}
```

Since you're attempting to pass a raw string literal here, you will need to be able to represent the JSON in string form, which requires you to escape the newline character.