# Prevent adding backslash to \n special character in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, string, replace

Let's use this as an example: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIID/TCCAuUCEQCxLmq67"

I want to preserve that string to be this string as I need this exact string.

But what's happening on the javascript side is that it is being displayed as:
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\\nMIID/TCCAuUCEQCxLmq67"

I believe this is the expected behavior as the \\n is effectively \n as the extra backslash is allowing javascript to interpret that string properly.

The issue is I am using JSON.stringify to pass in an object as a string into my API to store this information without the extra backslash.

Tried to replace the backslash but it seems to come back. Not quite sure what other approaches to try.. any help appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Am I understanding that you call `JSON.stringify` and it adds the extra slash as an escape character, but what you want is it to maintain the character as a newline `\n`?

Comment: `JSON.parse` can parse only if `\\n` is present and not `\n` in the client side. What is the Server side language / library you are using to parse the json?

Comment: Any reason you're not calling JSON.parse on your server?

Comment: @RyanWilson that is correct I want to leave \n as is and store the string in an object.

Comment: @Ramesh using serverless + golang for the backend.

Comment: @Alan I don't see why not, this is just the way the other APIs were written this exception case just came up

Comment: @justinseo - As per https://stackoverflow.com/q/56522226/30594 the `\\n` will be parsed correctly. as a matter of fact `\n` is invalid json literal.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to replace the \n with a random unique string/character and replace it again on server side if you want to keep the string with /n

```
let result = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIID/TCCAuUCEQCxLmq67".replaceAll("\n", "SomethingUnique");
```

// `result` is

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----SomethingUniqueMIID/TCCAuUCEQCxLmq67

Comment: this might be a last resort solution I may need to try! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the string with the escaped version:

```js
var x = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIID/TCCAuUCEQCxLmq67".replace("\n", "\\n")

console.log(x)
```

Comment: I don't think this works if its an object of strings